# Is there any way for cin input in horizontal position?

Tags: c++, user-input, cin

Good day! I am trying to solve a simple problem, but couldn't find any solution for it ^^

Is there any way to ask for user input (using 'cin') in a horizontal position?

Like for eg. format...
Name       Gender       Age     Civil Status
[Input]    [Input]    [Input]      [Input]

[image]

I'd tried with a solution only by using this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

  int main ()
  {
     std::string name, gender, cvl_stat;
     int age;

   std::cout << "Name";
   std::cout.width(20); std::cout << "Gender";
   std::cout.width(20); std::cout << "Age";
   std::cout.width(20); std::cout << "Civil Status";

   std::cin >> name >> gender >> age >> cvl_stat;

   return 0;

  }
```

Thank you guys! Keep safe! <3

Comment: You could read in the rest of the line then split on spaces. For more general answers you could try ncurses or other libraries (but that might be overkill for most simple purposes).

Comment: You could always use a more robust terminal library like ncurses to provide greater control over input elements. C++ itself has really weak support for this as it's expected to be provided by a library instead.